# how to use FBTestSession with Setup call of unit test

Tags: integration-testing, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to set up my unit test to use the latest facebook SDK and am running into issues...

Here is the code i have:

```
   [FBSession setDefaultAppID: @"323351877676429"];
FBTestSession *session = [FBTestSession sessionWithSharedUserWithPermissions: [NSArray array]];
STAssertNotNil(session, @"could not create test session");
[FBTestSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[]
                                   allowLoginUI:NO
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"completed");
                                    [FBSession setActiveSession: session];
                                  STAssertNil(error, error.description);
                                  STAssertNotNil(FBSession.activeSession, @"FBSession missing");
                                  STAssertNotNil(FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData, @"FBSession missing");
                                  STAssertNotNil(FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken, @"facebook token is nil");
                                  STAssertNotNil(session, @"FBSession missing");
                                  STAssertNotNil(session.accessTokenData, @"FBSession missing");
                                  STAssertNotNil(session.accessTokenData.accessToken, @"facebook token is nil");

                                  userModel *userM = [[userModel alloc] init];
                                  [userM awakeFromNib];
                              } ];
```

This works well except that as it runs asynchronously, when my test are run the session is not ready and thus i have session.accessTokenData == nil., which make my other test fail.

If i add the below code to my set up method after the openSession call, then the setup method never returns.

```
while (!FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData)
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.2];
```

Is there an exemple of proper use of FBTestSession somewhere? Any clue as to how to proceed?

Thanks, olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you just need to wait until the blocks are complete. Here is a working example (slightly shortened/modified) that you can use for reference.

```
- (void)testFacebookLogin {
    __block bool blockFinished = NO;
    FBTestSession *fbSession = [FBTestSession sessionWithSharedUserWithPermissions:@[@"email"]];
    [fbSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"session %@, status %d, error %@", session, status, error);
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

        FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
        NSLog(@"me request %@", me);
        [me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                          NSError *error) {
                STAssertNotNil(my.id, @"id shouldn't be nil");

                blockFinished = YES;
        }];
    }];

    // Run loop
    NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    while (blockFinished == NO && [loopUntil timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:loopUntil];
    }

}
```